# Data truncated issue in MySQL for Double/Decimal Value of Salary When Loading from CSV to MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

I have no idea what would possibly correct this issue - here is some of my data and its structure.
[image]

Here is the result of the Describe function to show my schema.
[image]

Here is the commands I've tried and their errors.

[image]

I've also tried reformatting salary as a FLOAT, as a DOUBLE(m,n), but both without success. What should I do in this case?

Comment: convert your salary column from a double to a decimal datatype i.e decimal(10,1)

Answer (score 1):

My answer will be a little strange but I came up to this a lot.

Just create every field as `VARCHAR(255)`, import all the data - the error will disapear - and analyze with care, there is always a field out of pattern.

After you find the different one, fix on the CSV or start to alter the fields:

```
ALTER TABLE Emp salary DOUBLE;
```